# Найти последнее слово между двумя нижними подчеркиваниями используя Regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например, дана строка some_text_text2_text3_asdasdasd. Нужно найти последнее слово между двумя нижними подчеркиваниями через regex. Для этой строки это подстрока text3. Спасибо за любую помощь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так (пример на JS):

```js
console.log(
  'some_text_text2_text3_asdasdasd'
  .match(/(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]*$)/)[0]
);
```

Ищем любое количество символов, отличных от почёркивания:

`[^_]+`

перед которыми есть подчёркивание:

`(?<=_)`

и после котрых есть подчёркивание, последнее в строке:

`(?=_[^_]*$)`

Если не поддерживается lookbehind, можно так:

```js
console.log(
  'some_text_text2_text3_asdasdasd'
    .match(/_([^_]+)(?=_[^_]*$)/)[1]
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень помогли)) Сейчас понял, что был близок к ответу, но просто не мог выбрать именно последнее подчеркивание

Comment: Прошу прощения, а можно ли чем-то заменить lookbehind здесь? Он не поддерживается многими браузерами, можно ли заменить данную строку? (?<=_)

Comment: @Никита Можно исключить подчёркивание из результата, введя запоминаемое подвыражение в скобках и используя его в результате. Я добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось )

Comment: @Никита, если ответ помог вам в решении задачи, то вы можете отблагодарить автора ответа выбрав его ответ как решение( установка галочки справа от ответа) и поставив положительную оценку.